# How use S4 extra sensors programmatically android

Tags: android, galaxy

I am developing an app which is available on the Play Store. It was built due to your help.

It uses various sensors to lock & unlock the phone. However, the Galaxy S4 has some more sensors like the Infrared, Temperature, Humidity, etc.

Is there any way to use those sensors? I would like to make  my app better for S4.

Comment: @user1587329 It is helpful, but doesn't answer the question. Moreover the question should be closed now